# Export all meshes in a single STL file

Tags: meshlab

If I loaded a STL file in MeshLab and I created a new mesh beside the loaded one, how can I export all of them as STL file ? Right now, if I export as STL what I see in viewer, I export just one mesh, not two which I see in viewer. What I missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine several meshes as previous step to exporting. Right click one of the meshes in the Layer dialog and select `Flatten visible layers`. If you are working with point clouds, you must check the `Keep unreferenced vertices` option.

[image]

Comment: Figured out  how to do this with `meshlabserver` from the command line here:  https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/105469/884